# Image - long tap

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Is there a way to detect a long tap on an image control in Xamarin Forms?

I'm using the carousel view to display images and would like to give the option to delete them by selecting with a long tap.

Comment: Check out this forum, the XLabs solution should work nicely:  https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/27323/how-can-i-recognize-long-press-gesture-in-xamarin-forms

Comment: you would either need to use a Custom Renderer to detect it at the platform level, or a 3rd party package like MRGestures.  The current set of built in gestures does not include a long tap.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your suggestions in the comments this is what I did:
(The purpose of the control is to be able to select an Image with a LongTap)

I defined my own Image control in the PCL:

- IsSelected BindableProperty.
- LongTap event.

  ```
   public class MyImage:Image
  {
          private BindableProperty IsSelectedProperty = BindableProperty.Create("IsSelected", typeof(bool), typeof(MyImage), false);

      public bool IsSelected {
          get {
              return (bool)GetValue(IsSelectedProperty);
          }
          set {
              SetValue(IsSelectedProperty, value);
          }
      }


      public event EventHandler LongClick;

      public void OnLongClick()
      {
          IsSelected = !IsSelected;

          if(IsSelected)
          {
              Opacity = 0.5;
          }
          else
          {
              Opacity = 1;
          }

          if (LongClick != null)
          {
              LongClick(this, EventArgs.Empty);
          }
      }
  }
  ```

And this is my custom renderer: (Defined in the Android project)

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyImage), typeof(MyImageRenderer))]
namespace PRISMCarouselView.Droid.Renderes
{
    public class MyImageRenderer : ImageRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Image> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                ImageView androidSource = Control as ImageView;
                MyImage myImage = e.NewElement as MyImage;

                androidSource.LongClick += (object sender, LongClickEventArgs ee) =>
                {
                    myImage.OnLongClick();
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit 1:**

Here's a slightly updated version, I use the BindingPropertyChangedDelegate to change the opacity of the image:

```
 public class SelectableImage : Image
    {
        public SelectableImage()
        {

        }

        private static BindableProperty IsSelectedProperty = BindableProperty.Create("IsSelected",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(SelectableImage),
        false, BindingMode.Default, null, (sender, o1, o2) => {

            SelectableImage imageControl = sender as SelectableImage;
            if(imageControl != null)
            {
                if(imageControl.IsSelected)
                {
                    imageControl.Opacity = 0.5;
                }else
                {
                    imageControl.Opacity = 1;
                }
            }
        });

        public bool IsSelected {
            get {
                return (bool)GetValue(IsSelectedProperty);
            }
            set {
                SetValue(IsSelectedProperty, value);
            }
        }


    }
```

And the renderer:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(SelectableImage), typeof(SelectableImageRenderer))]
namespace Muserma.Apps.Droid.Renderer
{
    public class SelectableImageRenderer : ImageRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Image> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                ImageView androidSource = Control as ImageView;
                SelectableImage selectableImage = e.NewElement as SelectableImage;

                androidSource.LongClick += (object sender, LongClickEventArgs ee) =>
                {
                    selectableImage.IsSelected = !selectableImage.IsSelected;
                };
            }
        }

    }
}
```